# How do I provide a string with a list of values to an "IN" statement

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005

I am creating a string that is a list of comma-delimitted values by looping through the selections in a CheckBoxList.  I am able to display this value, so I know that it is creating what I expect.  I am attempting to pass this list to an IN statment in a SELECT query:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT ThisDate, DATEPART(dw, ThisDate) AS Expr1 FROM fbCalendar WHERE (ThisDate &gt;= @ThisDate) AND (ThisDate &lt;= @ThisDate2) AND (DATEPART(dw, ThisDate) IN (@TheseDays))"

<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Label1" Name="TheseDays" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
```

This works fine as long as there is only a single item selected, but selecting a second item fails with the message:
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '4,5' to data type int.

However, I do not understand when this would be converted to an INT.  I have tried many different formatting attempts (such as encapsulating the string in parenthesis (e.g. "(4,5)" ) for the SELECT query, but I have yet to find the right one to make this work.  It seems like formatting is the problem, but perhaps I am missing something else.

Comment: I created a table to store the values to pass to the query.  It just doesn't seem right.

Comment: the problem is that the IN statement requires ticks around each string item in the list: IN('4', '5') and your process is passing in ('4, 5')

Answer (score 0):

Degan.

> I created a table to store the values to pass to the query.  It just
>   doesn't seem right.

You don't have to create an actual table. You can use a Table Valued Function and use that in your query e.g. as below.

```
(DATEPART(dw, ThisDate) IN (SELECT [item] FROM dbo.fnSplit(@TheseDays, ',')))
```

This uses the TVF from http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/13/10021854/fnsplit.aspx).

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnSplit(
    @sInputList VARCHAR(8000) -- List of delimited items
  , @sDelimiter VARCHAR(8000) = ',' -- delimiter that separates items
) RETURNS @List TABLE (item VARCHAR(8000))

BEGIN
DECLARE @sItem VARCHAR(8000)
WHILE CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0) <> 0
 BEGIN
 SELECT
  @sItem=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,1,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)-1))),
  @sInputList=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)+LEN(@sDelimiter),LEN(@sInputList))))

 IF LEN(@sItem) > 0
  INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sItem
 END

IF LEN(@sInputList) > 0
 INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sInputList -- Put the last item in
RETURN
END
GO
```